# Displaying only immediate child in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there way to display only immediate child pages in Wordpress. For example, I have page and sub page structure like:

```
Page 1
  Page 11
     Page 111
     Page 112
  Page 12
  Page 12
Page 2
  Page 21
  Page 22
     Page 221
     Page 222
```

So In above case, I want to list all child pages of Page 1 - Page 11, Page 12, Page 13. But I don't want to be listed Page 111 and Page 112, which is Wordpress's default behavior.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

Actually, I figure out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

```
$packages = get_pages('child_of=' . get_the_ID() .'&hierarchical=0&parent=' . get_the_ID());
```

Assume, I am browsing Page 1. To be noted, child_of= and parent= has same ID.

Answer (score 0):

See here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

In this function you can use depth to define the levels. Set it to 1 for displaying top level pages and set it to 2 for top and immediate sub level pages and so on. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking

Comment: The question is about retrieving pages - nothing to do with navigation menus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a menu, you can use the "depth" parameter in the `wp_nav_menu()` function, setting it to "1" for immediate siblings. However, there's no "depth" parameter in the `get_pages()` function. I built a short-code to display a sub-menu that's on a page (not a navigation menu), and it limits itself to immediate siblings or immediate children by checking on the parent of the page that's retrieved. Hope this is helpful:
[in_page_submenu level=’siblings’]

```
// two possible values of a "level" parameter in the shortcode args:
// "siblings" and "children"
add_shortcode('in_page_submenu', function ($args) {

        global $post;

        $this_page_id = $post->ID;
        $parent = $post->post_parent;
        $children = false;
        $siblings = false;

        if ( $args['level'] == "siblings" || !isset($args['level']) ) {
            $siblings = true;
            $query_arr = array(
                'child_of' => $parent,
                'exclude' => $this_page_id
            );

        } else if ($args['level'] == "children") {
            $children = true;
            $query_arr = array('child_of' => $post->ID);
        }

        $pages = get_pages($query_arr);

        $html = "<div>";

        foreach($pages as $p) {     

            $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($p);
            $display = true;

            if ($children && $parent_id != $this_page_id) {
                $display = false;
            }

            if ($siblings && $parent_id != $parent) {
                $display = false;
            }

            if ($display) {

                // do something with $html var

            }
        }

        $html .= "</div>";

        return $html;

});
```